# Integrating Firebase Existing Web Application

Tags: sql, firebase, react-native

I'm creating a mobile app for a web application built using MySQL.  The app however is being built in using react/ react-native and too my knowledge requires the use of Firebase.  How would I get Firebase to share information with private servers to share information on a live basis?

Comment: Please define share and give an example of the flow

Comment: _How would I get Firebase to share information with private servers to share information on a live basis?_ 
I didn't get this can you please elaborate.

Comment: Sorry I'm not really sure what you meant by "the flow" @AlexMounir  So I have a web app already created using a MySQL database.  I'm using react/react-native to create a app for the iOS and android platforms, but this requires me to us firebase.  both the web app and mobile app will share user data and need to have a synchronous user experience.  Is there an api or way to link the two databases